# In Mercenaries mode, is there a way to see how many tasks a mercenary has completed?

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone's Mercenaries mode, each mercenary has 18 tasks that they can complete for rewards. When a mercenary is visiting your campfire, you can see their current task and make progress toward it. However, when a mercenary is not at your campfire I don't see any way to see how many of their 18 tasks they have completed.

Is there a way to see how many tasks a mercenary has completed? Is there a way to see which mercenaries have completed all 18 of their tasks?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone else would be looking for the answer for that question, but just in case:

At the fireplace screen, you can switch tab to see current personal quest of each mercenary. Simply scroll down for the list of those grayed-out mercs with all quests finished.